# How to use Navigation relay satellite in X2:The threat?

Tags: x2-the-threat

The problem with this game is that not only it lacks in game help but there's also next to nothing about it on the internet.

I bought a Navigation relay satellite at a trading station. I'm not 100% what it does, and absolutely no idea how to install it in the current system. How does that satellite work?

Answer (score 1):

Navigation relay satellites provide you with a data feed in your sector map when you are no longer in the sector. You can also buy new ships remotely from the Shipyards within the sector if you have the trading system extension installed. Advanced satellites have double the range.

Typically speaking you want to place your satellites 10-20km outside of any major flight path as to avoid having them destroyed, you can also try to use values like -20/-15 or +20/+15, but watch for any portals or paths get too close.